# Facebook FB.login not awaiting response

Tags: facebook

given the following code: ` const handleFacebookLogin = (e: any) => {
console.log('called login')

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        console.log('login status response', response)
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            console.log('logged in correctly')
        } else {
            window['FB'].login(function (response2) {
                console.log('logged in', response2)
            }, fbOptions)
        }
    })

    console.log('finished click handler')
}`
```

the response returning response2 happens before the user dialog is has even been filled out.   I would think that FB would wait for a user name and password BEFORE calling the callback function, or am I crazy?

I have tried everything I can find on SO and all other resources I can find.  I would expect that once a user enters FB credentials and the call is made THEN the callback function would happen instead of a linear execution of code.

Comment: so the click event handler from a button (TS, React, NextJS) fires this code, console logs: 'called login', 'logged in', 'finished click handler' while the FB dialog is open and untouched.   Once you complete the logon, the dialog closes and the auth response stored in the cookie is 'uknown'